# How do you cache images to be drawn later in canvas2d in dart?

Tags: image, caching, canvas, dart, 2d-context-api

So, I got how to draw images in canvas using dart, which goes something like this:

```
    ///create the image element with given source
    ImageElement myImage = new ImageElement(src:"myImage.png");

    ///load the image
    myImage.onLoad.listen((event){
         ///when the image is loaded, draw it
         myContext.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
    });
```

But, how do you draw an image at a later date?

As in, say I have a list of images:

```
    List<ImageElement> myImageList;
```

I want to then load all my image elements one by one given their source. Then when that's done, whenever I feel like it, I can just go:

```
    myContext.drawImage(myImageList[i], x, y);
```

without this code being inside the onLoad.listen method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Future.wait](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Future.html#wait) to wait `onLoad` on every images :

```dart
Future.wait(myImageList.map((e) => e.onLoad.single)).then((_){
  myContext.drawImage(myImageList[i], x, y);
  // or call function that assumes that images are loaded
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Futures are awesome. On a side note, I want to add (after looking into futures), that the window.animationFrame future is awesome. 

Basically, what I did is encapsulate my code into a void draw(double dt) and then call window.animationFrame.then(draw). This gives me the flexibility of clearing the canvas between each frame and letting the futures handling everything. 

As an optimization, I've extended ImageElement to add a isLoaded flag so that, if I call draw on draw when the image isn't loaded, to just not try drawing.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to validate the answer.

Comment: Done :) Sorry, new to stackoverflow.